# sequelize you are using sql safe update error

Tags: mysql, sql, orm, nodes, sequelize.js

I am getting this error randomly . I am deleting from **activeusers** table on the basis of username it gives me error sometime and works smoothly sometime.
here is my code for deleting

let say

```
 data={nickname:'asad',id:1}
 activeusers.destroy({where:{username:data.nickname} }).then(res=>{
 });
```

I have turn off the sql safe update from sql workbench but problem still exists
how can i permanently get rid from this error 
[image]

Comment: WHoo red on black how can you read that?

Comment: is't that interesting  @P.Salmon

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem with updates in MySQL.  Here is your query:

```
DELETE FROM ActiveUsers WHERE username = 'mazhar.hayat@ibexglobal.com'
```

The error stems from that you are not using a primary key column in the `WHERE` clause.  You would also see this error if you had no `WHERE` clause at all.  MySQL has a mode which views a DML query like this as unsafe, because it is broad and runs the risk of corrupting your data.

There is a hack solution to this which might work.  You could modify the query to mention the primary key column as follows:

```
DELETE
FROM ActiveUser
WHERE username = 'mazhar.hayat@ibexglobal.com' AND id=id
```

This might spoof MySQL into thinking the query is safe, because it mentions the primary key column `id` in the `WHERE` clause.

But what I would recommend to you is turning off safe updates mode directly in MySQL.  Edit your startup script and make sure that `--safe-updates` and `--i-am-a-dummy` are not mentioned in the script.

**Edit:**

If you wanted to handle this from `destroy`, then the query option is the only option:

```
Post.findAll(
    { where: ["username = ? AND id = id", data.nickname] }
).success()
```

Comment: I am using sequelize how can i do this in sequelize destroy function

Comment: @Asad Then you would have to try the query trick, q.v. my edit.  Note that I don't recommend this; configure your MySQL server to turn off safe updates mode.  This is preferable to peppering your JavaScript code with MySQL configuration stuff.

Comment: I have turn off this setting but it got random behavior :(

Comment: @Asad How did you turn it off?  If you turned it off at the session level, then each new session would also require turning it off.

Comment: I turned it off my clicking on workbench `edit` menu then `prefrences` => then `SQL editor` and then unmarking the `safe_update` option @Tim

Comment: your query is not working it saying support for literal replacement in the  "where" object has removed

Comment: I am not a Sequelize expert, it should be possible to do this.  But in any case, the best long term solution is to handle this within MySQL.

Comment: can you tell me how to turn off safe update mode permanently for mysql server

Comment: Im using nodejs

Comment: well I have used SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0; thank you for ur time upvoted :D

Comment: @Asad I also upvoted your question, maybe a JavaScript person can give you the exact answer you want.